# Declaring a variable used in SELECT throws an exception

Tags: t-sql

I have the following code:

```
DECLARE @d AS INT
SELECT @d = DATEDIFF(d, p.CreatedOn, GETDATE()),
    CASE
       WHEN @d <= 30 THEN
         @d * 5
       ELSE p.Count
    END Sort
FROM table p
ORDER BY Sort
```

This throws an error

> A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.

My actual formula within the WHEN is very complicated so I figured I reuse the variable since it's used 9 or 10 times. Any options?

Once this works, I actually need to create a computed column out of this, so not sure if variables can be used there but baby steps I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define a variable inline. If you want to reuse a computer column, wrap it inside a CTE:

```
;WITH
    cte AS
    (
        SELECT  *,
                DayCount = DATEDIFF(d, p.CretaedOn, GETDATE()) 
        FROM    table p
    )

SELECT      CASE
                WHEN DayCount <= 30 THEN DayCount * 5
                WHEN ...
            END         Sort
FROM        cte
ORDER BY    Sorc
```